# Dynamically select a concrete object with a name using SimpleInjector

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

How can I use Simple Injector DI container to register multiple concrete types of `IShipper` interface and dynamically select them using a `name`?

If I can't register multiple instances of the same type, is there a different way to do with Simple Injector?

```
public Setup()
{
    var container = new SimpleInjector.Container();
    // TODO: Registration required for two different shippers
    container.Register<UPS, IShipper>();
}

public interface IShipper
{
    void Ship(Product product)
}

public class UPS : IShipper { ... }

public class FedEx : IShipper { ... }

public void Ship(String shipper, Product product)
{
    // TODO: Retrieve the shipper by name
    var shipper = container.GetInstance<IShipper>();
    shipper.Ship(product);
}

Ship("FedEx", new Product());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this, for instance you could:

- Define a `IShipperFactory` that allows retrieving a `IShipper`.
- Create a proxy that implements `IShipper` and delegates to the real `IShipper` implementation; this works in case the `Product` entity itself contains information about the shipper.
- Create a 'dispatcher`that forwards the call to the proper`IShipper`internally, without exposing this`IShipper` abstraction back to the client.

The documentation [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#resolve-instances-by-key) gives some clues about how to create multiple registrations of the same abstraction.

Here's an example using a dispatcher:

```
public interface IShippingDispatcher
{
    void Ship(string shipper, Product product);
}

public class ShippingDispatcher : IShippingDispatcher
{
    private readonly Func<string, IShipper> factory;
    public ShippingDispatcher(Func<string, IShipper> factory) { this.factory = factory; }
    public void Ship(string shipper, Product product) => factory(shipper).Ship(product);
}
```

As an example, you can have the following setup with this:

```
public Setup()
{
    var container = new Container();

    var shippers = new Dictionary<string, InstanceProducer<IShipper>>
    {
        { "FedEx", Lifestyle.Transient.CreateProducer<IShipper, FedEx>(container) },
        { "UPS", Lifestyle.Transient.CreateProducer<IShipper, UPS>(container) },
    };

    container.RegisterSingleton<IShippingDispatcher>(
        new ShippingDispatcher(shipper => shippers[shipper].GetInstance()));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to go about this.
https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#collections
https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#resolve-instances-by-key

The approach you are describing sounds like the second link.  However I would generally go with the approach described in the first link and add a property `Name` to the IShipper interface and do something like `var shipper = shippers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "FedEx");`

```
 public interface IShipper
 {
     string Name { get; }
     void Ship(Product product)
 }

public Setup()
{
    var container = new SimpleInjector.Container();
    // TODO: Registration required for two different shippers
    container.RegisterCollection<IShipper>(new[] { new UPS(), new FedEx() });
}

public void Ship(string shipperName, Product product)
{
    // TODO: Retrieve the shipper by name
    var shippers = container.GetAllInstances<IShipper>();
    var shipper = shippers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == shipperName);
    // TODO: do null check on shipper
    shipper.Ship(product);
}
```